# Cannot install Flutter on MacOS blg sur terminal

Tags: flutter

I am not able to install flutter on my mac book.

There is no problem entering the SDK.
But after that is the problem. Run the terminal app and enter the path.
I watch lectures, watch YouTube, and follow them, but I can't.

i changed "bash -> zsh", and write 'vim ~/.zshrc'
and enter, but see a message like the one below.
what is the problem?....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9yaO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9yaO.png)

Answer (score 1):

VIM created a .swp file so you can't open two instances of the same file.

You may want to use `nano` command which is less complex to use than VIM to update your path in your .zshrc file